# How to use "global variables" using express and node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, variables, routes

Basically, I'm developing a web application in which the user will be able to create research protocols, such protocols will have several research samples and, therefore, I wanted to organize this in a database. So, I created two routes in my application, one of them to update the protocol data and another one for its samples and I wanted to define an "id_protocols" to join the samples to their respective protocols. But for some reason it just doesn't work, the value is always undefined. Here is the code:

```
    let id_protocol;

    // C - Protocols
    app.post('/create-protocols', (req, res) => {
        const { name_protocol, objective_protocol } = req.body;
        db.run(`INSERT INTO tbl_protocols (name_protocol, objective_protocol) VALUES (?, ?)`, [ name_protocol, objective_protocol ], function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).send('Error creating protocol.');
            };
            id_protocol = this.lastID;
        });
    });

    // C - Samples
    app.post('/create-samples', (req, res) => {
        const name_sample = req.body.name_sample
        const description_sample = req.body.description_sample
        db.run(`INSERT INTO tbl_samples (name_sample, description_sample, id_protocol) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`, [ name_sample, description_sample, id_protocol ], function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return res.status(500).send('Error creating sample.');
            };
        });
    });
//
```

can you help me?

I was trying to declare the "id protocol" outside the routes, thus leaving the global variable, but that didn't work either

Comment: That's not a very good approach in general. What if you have two or more users at the same time? The first request should return the id to the client which would then pass it along with the second request.

Comment: If a "protocol ID" is an input for "creating a sample" then shouldn't it be included in the request for creating a sample?  I'm not really seeing the need for server-side statefulness here.

Comment: Per user state should NOT be stored in regular server variables or any scope.  Doing so just creates conflicts between multiple users using your server around the same time frame and nearly all servers expect to be used by multiple users.  Instead, your server should either be stateless (all state kept in the client and sent with a given request as needed) or you should store state for a user in a per user session (that is usually indexed by a cookie ID).  The less per-user state you can have the better (zero is best).